manually edit a clipboard with perl command?
I am using clipboard and xr-hyper in Overleaf to copy/paste text from A.tex to B.tex. Because I sometime \Copy{text \label{blabla}} from A and \Paste into into B, this will create duplicated labels (i.e. label blabla is both in A and B).
The workaround I have been thinking of would be to manually modify the output of the clipboard, changing say \label{blabla} to \label{transfer:blabla}, which would resolve the duplicate (i.e. blabla refers to A and transfer:blabla to B).
How can I use latexmkrc to achieve this? I tried adding the following to manually update clipboard.cpy, but it doesn't seem to have any effect?:
sub preprocessing {
    system("perl -pi -e 's/\\s*label\s*\{(?!transfer:)(\S*)/\\label{transfer:$1/g' output-clipboard.cpy");
}

maybe this is because of the chain of events, and I am not adding it at the right time (iei before the clipboard is re-generated?)? Or am I missing a add_cus_dep line?
thanks!

I'm not sure you already provided enough information to replicate and try your problem ...

I have no idea what clipboard does, and you have provided no example, but xr (xr-hyper) has a standard mechanism for avoiding duplicated labels
